# vitest cannot run tests with apollo client query in them

Tags: graphql, rollup, vitest

For our GraphQL server, we are trying to move our tests from `jest` to `vitest`, but are having issues with our integration tests. They use Apollo Client codegen to generate types for the queries used in the integration tests. An example could look like this:

```js
import { GlobalUsersService } from '../__generated__/asset';
import { mockOperation } from './mockOperation';
import {
  UserNameQuery,
  UserNameQueryVariables,
} from '../__generated__/test-types/graphql';
import { gql } from '../__generated__/test-types/gql';

const userNameQuery = gql(/* GraphQL */ `
  query UserName($emailAddress: String!) {
    user(emailAddress: $emailAddress) {
      ... on User {
        firstName
      }
    }
  }
`);

describe('verification test setup verification', () => {
  it('overrides context defaults', async () => {
    const firstNameMock = 'Svend';
    const emailToQuery = 'some-email@domain.com';

    const usersSpy = vi
      .spyOn(GlobalUsersService, 'getGlobalUserByEmailAddress')
      .mockResolvedValue({
        globalUsers: [
          {
            firstName: firstNameMock,
            b2CObjectId: 'someID',
          },
        ],
      });

    const result = await mockOperation<UserNameQuery, UserNameQueryVariables>(
      userNameQuery,
      {
        emailAddress: emailToQuery,
      },
      {
        // Override context.user with signInName to satisfy auth scope
        user: {
          signInName: emailToQuery,
        },
      }
    );

    expect(usersSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    const { firstName } = result.data.user;

    expect(firstName).toEqual(firstNameMock);
  });
});
```

Our `vitest.config.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
// import graphql from '@rollup/plugin-graphql';

export default defineConfig(() => ({
  // plugins: [graphql()],
  test: {
    // In order to access `vi` in tests without having to import it, as was the practice in Jest
    globals: true,
    environment: 'node',
    globalSetup: './src/globalJestSetup.ts',
    reporters: ['verbose'],
    include: ['./src/**/*.{test,spec}.ts'],
    coverage: {
      include: ['src/**/*'],
      exclude: ['src/__generated__'],
    },
  },
}));
```

This gives the error

```
Error: Expression expected
 ❯ getRollupError node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:376:41
 ❯ convertProgram node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:1040:26
 ❯ parseAstAsync node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:2186:12
 ❯ ssrTransformScript node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-jvB8WLp9.js:54248:15
 ❯ loadAndTransform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-jvB8WLp9.js:53796:11
```

If I then introduce the `@rollup/plugin-graphql` plugin (the outcommented lines added back in and tests rerun), I instead get the following error:

```
Error: typeDefs must contain only strings, documents, schemas, or functions, got object
 ❯ visitTypeSources node_modules/@graphql-tools/schema/node_modules/@graphql-tools/merge/esm/typedefs-mergers/merge-typedefs.js:61:19
     59| }
     60| export function mergeGraphQLTypes(typeSource, config) {
     61|     var _a, _b, _c;
       |                   ^
     62|     resetComments();
     63|     const allNodes = visitTypeSources(typeSource, config);
```

Looking at that function:

```
function visitTypeSources(typeSource, options, allNodes = [], visitedTypeSources = new Set()) {
    if (typeSource && !visitedTypeSources.has(typeSource)) {
        visitedTypeSources.add(typeSource);
        if (typeof typeSource === 'function') {
            visitTypeSources(typeSource(), options, allNodes, visitedTypeSources);
        }
        else if (Array.isArray(typeSource)) {
            for (const type of typeSource) {
                visitTypeSources(type, options, allNodes, visitedTypeSources);
            }
        }
        else if (isSchema(typeSource)) {
            const documentNode = getDocumentNodeFromSchema(typeSource, options);
            visitTypeSources(documentNode.definitions, options, allNodes, visitedTypeSources);
        }
        else if (isStringTypes(typeSource) || isSourceTypes(typeSource)) {
            const documentNode = parse(typeSource, options);
            visitTypeSources(documentNode.definitions, options, allNodes, visitedTypeSources);
        }
        else if (typeof typeSource === 'object' && isDefinitionNode(typeSource)) {
            allNodes.push(typeSource);
        }
        else if (isDocumentNode(typeSource)) {
            visitTypeSources(typeSource.definitions, options, allNodes, visitedTypeSources);
        }
        else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(typeSource));
            throw new Error(`typeDefs must contain only strings, documents, schemas, or functions, got ${typeof typeSource}`);
        }
    }
    return allNodes;
}
```

and the console.log I added

```
{
  "default": {
    "kind": "Document",
    "definitions": [theDefinitionsForTheProject...],
    "loc": {
      "start": 0,
      "end": 4873,
      "source": {
        "body": "enum OurEnums...",
        "name": "GraphQL request",
        "locationOffset": { "line": 1, "column": 1 }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the passed object is of kind `document`, so doesn't hit any of the clauses. Maybe I'm going about it all wrong?

Any ideas on where to go from here would be much appreciated. Is there perhaps another rollup plugin I should use?